# No me deja crear la base de datos en phpmyadmin y me da este error: #1064

Tags: sql, mariadb

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'KEY(id) )' at line 8

y esto es lo que yo eh programado:

```
CREATE DATABASE blog;
USE blog;
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
        activo TINYINT NOT NULL,
        PRYMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo correcto es `PRIMARY KEY`, tú has puesto `PRYMARY KEY`.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias me ayudo a mi tambien